# Play animation after another animation on sprite

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, cocos2d-iphone

I've looked all over and i can't find any information on how to do this. I want to run an action animation then right after that animation is done i want it to run another action animation all on the same sprite. how is this possible?

```
    [self.mainShip runAction:retractdoor];
    [self.mainShip runAction:activatedoor];
```

this crashes me.

```
    self.mainShip runAction: [CCSequence actions:retractdoor,activatedoor, nil];
```

gives me a yellow notification

incompatible pointer types sending Cc action to parameter of type ccfinite time action

```
CCAnimation *retractdoorAnimation = [CCAnimation
                                         animationWithSpriteFrames:retractdoorframes delay:0.1f];
    CCAnimation *activatedoorAnimation = [CCAnimation
                                           animationWithSpriteFrames:activatedoorframes delay:0.1f];

self.retractdoorAction = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:retractdoorAnimation];
self.activatedoorAction = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:activatedoorAnimation];
```

Comment: `self.mainShip runAction: [CCSequence actions: [retractdoor] [activatedoor]];` - how does that even compile

Comment: `self.mainShip runAction: [CCSequence actions: retractdoor, activatedoor, nil];`, you can't use brackets if you don't call a method, you have to separate by comma, and you have to terminate with `nil`. That would have never compiled.

Comment: show the code where you declare both actions.

Comment: I added them in my edited post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you missed the nil termination.

```
[self.mainShip runAction: [CCSequence actions:retractdoor,activatedoor, nil]];
```

this should work, dont use the square brackets and dont miss the comma..

Comment: incompatible pointer types sending Cc action to parameter of type ccfinite time action

Comment: because CCAnimation is not a CCAction, you need to do something like CCAnimate *anim1 = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:retractdoorAnimation  restoreOriginalFrame:NO]; and then put the anim1 into the sequence